# create list definition under sub site in site definition

Tags: visual-studio, list-definition, site-definition, sub-site

I want to Create List Definition & List Instance under particular Sub-site.It can not been seen under site Collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accomplished with the following code in Feature Activated event receiver.

```
SPSite site = null;
SPWeb web = null;
site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
web = site.AllWebs["SubSite"];
SPListTemplate temp = web.ListTemplates["ListDefinition"];
Guid newg = web.Lists.Add("ListInstance", "Description", temp);
SPList newlist = web.Lists[newg];
newlist.OnQuickLaunch = true;
newlist.Update();
```

Comment: This will make List Named listInstance on Custom ListDefinition named listDefinition.

Answer (score 1):

Create your List Definition using a Web Scoped feature. Set the feature attributes to *Hidden=True*.

You can then activate your feature manually using PowerShell for that sub-site.

For further automation you can either staple your feature to specific templates (so it is automatically included in sites which uses a specific template) or reference it in the *WebFeatures* element in the Onet.xml of your custom site definition.